# What are these weird symbols in bash terminal in vs code. I am working with Django. How to fixed it?

Tags: django, terminal, symbols, django-migrations

```
$ python manage.py migrate
?[36;1mOperations to perform:?[0m
?[1m  Apply all migrations: ?[0madmin, auth, contenttypes, my_app, sessions
?[36;1mRunning migrations:?[0m
  Applying my_app.0001_initial...?[32;1m OK?[0m
```

In a course i am following the guy terminal doesn't show those kind of messed up characters.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is, that Django tries to dye your text, for estatic reasons.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-do-i-print-colored-text-to-the-terminal) for more info about the coloring.
There a various Option to fix this:

#### 1. Use another terminal

It might help to use another terminal tool that interpretes the color orders by Django.

#### 2. Disable colors

You can also disable the color feature.

Add `USE_TERMINAL_COLORS = False` to your settings file.

or

Run `export DJANGO_NOCOLOR` in your terminal.

For more information see [this](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12112) Django isssue.

Hope that helps.